# Building a web application for microsoft edge sidebar

Tags: asp.net, database, azure, microsoft-edge

What do I need in to start off building a web application in edge, specifically that only need to work in the sidebar. If you can give me some terms to google that points me in the right direction, it would be really appreciated. I'm looking to create something similar to sticky notes, that only works in the sidebar.

Tried googling but none of the results matched what I am looking for

Comment: Not quite clear if you are looking for web app with extension on Edge. Anyway see if this serves your requirement. `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/getting-started/part1-simple-extension?tabs=v3`

Comment: I'm not really sure you should care if the user has Chrome, Edge, or Firefox, or even a mobile phone. So, it does not make a whole lot of sense to "limit" your quesiton and context to that of the Edge browser unless good reason exists. In other words, you would want to adopt some top menu, or side bar menu, and one that works in all browsers. As such, you probably should adopt a bootstrap menu, since their are options to have such menus going across the top of the page, or down the side of the page. As such, one should not really care if using browser x, y or z.

Answer (score -1):

I see that Avilon has provided you with a link to the "Creating Extension Tutorial". You can also refer to the following link:

1.Extension concepts and architecture: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/getting-started/

2.Extensions in the Microsoft Edge sidebar：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/sidebar

3.Supported APIs for Microsoft Edge extensions：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/api-support

Comment: fyi the question is off-topic - it's just a request for info. And link-only answers are not valid answers.